# Map based GeoData search toolware?

Tags: leaflet, search

Assume we have a well populated PostGIS database with lots of metadata about raster and feature based data.

What open source technologies would one use to create a end-user friendly catalog search and download system (web based).

Something similar to what is located at: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset

(I realize they just provide pointers to the original source, we would be caching the rasters and the feature in a datalake, and using PostGIS for the catalog/index)
yea, the data.gov uses ESRI, but let's take that off the table.

If I had to do it by hand, I would use Leaflet or OpenLayers, but since this is such a common need, I wonder if someone has not already put that together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://geonetwork-opensource.org/
There are many Metadata Catalog Products and that Publish Data into CSW, SOCRATA, CKAN open Data searchable formats

Comment: Ok, this looks like a complete solution (Harvest, catalog, access controls, logging, and Web GUI search (OpenLook). Anything you recommend? Is this the best of the breed today?

Comment: ​I am pretty happy with fme server for the backend. Can geonetwork be combined with fme?